# Prediction plot from binomial glm/regression - prediction line does not go up to 1 on the y-axis

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, linear

I have a binomial glm looking at the probability of an otter road traffic accident occurring when considering a host of environmental factors.

Model is running fine, but the prediction plot line for the probability of an otter RTA while looking at distance to nearest town, does not hit 1 on the y-axis? I've plotted other prediction plots for my other environmental variables which look fine (usually an S shaped curve and they hit both 0 and 1, but this plot doesn't. It only goes up to 0.3 ish.

Does anyone know what is causing this or if this is right? The model says the effect of distance to nearest town is significant p<0.05 as is a negative intercept. I'm really lost on why this prediction plot looks off?

Any help would be massively appreciated[image]

Comment: Unless your model forces the probability at a distance of 0 to be 1, there's no reason to expect the result to have this property.  You can obtain specific answers and recommendations if you would share the details of your model.

Comment: Even for small distances, there are non-real-otter RTAs (i.e., zeros). There is no distance below which *every* RTA is a real-otter RTA (i.e., a one). Thus, a fitted/predicted probability that is well below 1 is completely correct.

Comment: @StephanKolassa thank you! That makes sense, I'm not sure why I was inclined to expect the prediction line to reach the probability of 1.. so is this implying a weak negative probability? And would I report this by saying the probability of a real RTA occurring is slightly larger on roads closer to towns? Not quite sure how to report it!

Comment: @whuber thank you! my model is a binomial glm, dependent variable is 0's and 1's: random control points (0's) and real otter RTA's (1's). Modelled with 3 other env variables include road width, dist to river crossing and road topography (categorical)

Comment: Yes, "the probability of a real RTA occurring is slightly larger on roads closer to towns" sounds like a perfectly good way of reporting this, especially if you also show your plot.

Answer (score 3):

This is no different than if you took one of those S shaped curves that you are familiar with and cropped it to look at one side or the other. Just look at the data points at the left-most side of your graph (distance to town near 0km) -- there are "real otter" points at the top but even more "fake otter" points at the bottom, so of course the probability of being a real otter for that distance should be less than 50%, let alone exactly 100%. In those other examples, the range of observed values on the x-axis presumably had one extreme where nearly all the data points were zero, and the other where nearly all the data points were one; that's just not the case here.

Now, if you took this function and calculated its value over a wider range, you'd eventually see it approach probabilities near 1 even further to the left, way into the negative values. Of course, you and I know that negative distances aren't possible, and so you'd never actually make that plot. (Also, regression models should generally not be trusted when they are *extrapolated* in this manner far outside the range of observed predictor variables, unless there's some domain specific reason to believe that the regression function reflects an underlying principle.)

Comment: thank you for your response! Definitely helps me make more sense of it.. do you have any suggestions on how I would report this? Seems a bit more tricky... or would it simply be that there is a weak probability of real otter RTA's occurring on roads closer to towns? Thanks so much!